# Can I make this mySQL query faster?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

I have the following entry in mysql-slow.log:

```
# Time: 180506 21:57:03
# User@Host: mysqlserver[mysqlserver] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 88.963476  Lock_time: 0.000088 Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 114197

SET timestamp=1525633023;

SELECT n1.full_name AS sender_full_name, s1.email AS sender_email, e.subject, e.body, 
e.attach, e.date, e.id, r.status, n2.full_name AS receiver_full_name,
s2.email AS receiver_email, r.basket 
FROM people_emails p 
JOIN email_routing r ON r.receiver_email_id = 3223 AND r.status = 2 
JOIN email e ON e.id = r.message_id 
JOIN people_emails s1 ON s1.id = r.sender_email_id 
JOIN people n1 ON n1.id = s1.people_id 
JOIN people_emails s2 ON s2.id = r.receiver_email_id 
JOIN people n2 ON n2.id = s2.people_id  
WHERE p.internal_user_id = 314 
ORDER BY e.date desc 
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

The result of that query is similar to this:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |sender_full_name|sender_email|subject|body| attach | date |  id  |status|receiver_full_name|basket| 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |John Blow       |jb@corp.lan |Aloha  |Text|        |180506|856050|2     |Mary Johns        |1     |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is all the data about the query and the used tables:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT n1.full_name AS sender_full_name, s1.email AS sender_email, 
e.subject, e.body, e.attach, e.date, e.id, r.status, n2.full_name AS receiver_full_name, 
s2.email AS receiver_email, r.basket, 'user777' FROM people_emails p 
JOIN email_routing r ON r.receiver_email_id = 3233 AND r.status = 2 
JOIN email e ON e.id = r.message_id 
JOIN people_emails s1 ON s1.id = r.sender_email_id 
JOIN people n1 ON n1.id = s1.people_id 
JOIN people_emails s2 ON s2.id = r.receiver_email_id 
JOIN people n2 ON n2.id = s2.people_id 
WHERE p.internal_user_id = 314 ORDER BY e.date desc LIMIT 0, 50; 

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len     ref                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      s2      const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       const                   1       Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      n2      const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       const                   1   
1   SIMPLE      p       ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL                    18631   Using where
1   SIMPLE      r       ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL                    899567  Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE      e       eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       server.r.message_id     1   
1   SIMPLE      s1      eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       server.r.sender_email_id1   
1   SIMPLE      n1      eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       server.s1.people_id     1   



SHOW CREATE TABLE people_emails; 
CREATE TABLE `people_emails` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nick` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `key_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `people_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `activity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `internal_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22114 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

SHOW CREATE TABLE email_routing; 
CREATE TABLE `email_routing` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sender_email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `receiver_email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `basket` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `popup` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tm` int(11) NOT NULL,
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=987389 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

SHOW CREATE TABLE email; 
CREATE TABLE `email` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `subject` text NOT NULL,
 `body` text NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `attach` text NOT NULL,
 `attach_ondisk` text NOT NULL,
 `attach_dir` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 DEFAULT NULL,
 `attach_subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `attach_content` longtext,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `Index_2` (`attach_dir`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `path` (`attach_dir`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=856151 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

SHOW CREATE TABLE people; 
CREATE TABLE `people` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `lname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `patronymic` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
 `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `people_type_id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tags` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `job` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `post` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `profession` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 DEFAULT NULL,
 `zip` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `region` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `address_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `inner` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `contact_through` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
 `next_call` date NOT NULL,
 `additional` text CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `changed` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nick` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_update_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `area` text NOT NULL,
 `reviewed_` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `phones_old` text NOT NULL,
 `post_sticker` text NOT NULL,
 `permissions` int(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `internal_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `most_used` (`category`,`status`,`city`,`lname`,`next_call`),
 KEY `registrars` (`category`,`status`,`contact_through`,`next_call`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `lname` (`lname`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fname` (`fname`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `mname` (`patronymic`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `Full Name` (`full_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=415009 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

While getting the above output as per request from the comment I have also noticed that my tables are all in different format - MyISAM and InnoDB. Can that be a part of the problem too?

Did I made the tables structure too complicated? I would like to understand what part of the query makes this so slow so I can re-arrange my tables.

Comment: Any question about query optimization should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table in your query, so we know what indexes you currently have. Also the output of `EXPLAIN <query>` for the query you are trying to optimize.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you, just by doing that I see that my tables are mix of MyISAM and InnoDB which also can be part of the problem, I guess

Comment: So the lack of any usable index on the two biggest datasets p and r) is an obvious place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to eliminate the entries from your EXPLAIN report where `type=ALL`. This means it's doing a table-scan, and that's bad for performance if it happens on a large table.

In your case, you have *two* tables that are doing table-scans. Check the numbers in the `row` column of the explain, 18631 and 899567. Multiply them together = 16,759,832,777. That's how many row combinations the query will potentially examine!

Part of the problem is that your query is doing a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). You have no conditions relating your table `p` to the other tables. So for every row examined in `p`, it combines this with the rows examined in other tables. This has a very high cost.

It's not clear why you even have `p` in your query, since it's not related to the other tables, and you don't fetch any columns from it in the select-list. I can produce the result set you described even when I take `p` out of the query:

```
SELECT n1.full_name AS sender_full_name, s1.email AS sender_email,
e.subject, e.body, e.attach, e.date, e.id, r.status, n2.full_name AS receiver_full_name,
s2.email AS receiver_email, r.basket, 'user777'
FROM email_routing r
JOIN email e ON e.id = r.message_id
JOIN people_emails s1 ON s1.id = r.sender_email_id
JOIN people n1 ON n1.id = s1.people_id
JOIN people_emails s2 ON s2.id = r.receiver_email_id
JOIN people n2 ON n2.id = s2.people_id
WHERE r.receiver_email_id = 3233 AND r.status = 2
ORDER BY e.date desc LIMIT 0, 50;
```

I also suggest adding this index:

```
ALTER TABLE email_routing ADD KEY bk1 (receiver_email_id, status,
    sender_email_id, message_id, basket);
```

This helps the search for `r.receiver_email_id = 3233 AND r.status = 2`.

The additional columns are in the index to make it a *covering index*. This means the query doesn't have to read the email_routing table at all, if it gets all the columns it needs from the index.

EXPLAIN for this query looks better, now that none of the tables are doing `type=ALL`, and one of them shows "Using index" which is the indicator of the covering index.

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s2    | const  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const                  |    1 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n2    | const  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const                  |    1 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | bk1           | bk1     | 8       | const,const            |    1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.r.sender_email_id |    1 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.s1.people_id      |    1 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.r.message_id      |    1 | NULL                            |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

P.S.: MyISAM vs. InnoDB makes little difference for this query optimization. The index will help a lot for both storage engines. But I always recommend to convert to InnoDB (see my answer to [MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717)).

Comment: Thank you, great! I though I was using p table for security reason to make sure that user gets only those rows which belongs to his user_id, but you are right, the receiver_email_id can be used without checking user_id, thank you for this. My server has run now for some hours and the with this corrected query mySQL load drastically dropped, so I'm getting those queries in 2-3 sections now instead of 88 as it was before

Comment: I have also tried to convert the tables to InnoDB but my SQL version is below 5.6 (because it is old Ubuntu server 12.04) and I couldn't do ...WHERE r.receiver_email_id = 3233 AND r.status = 2 MATCH (n1.full_name, s1.email, e.subject, e.body, e.attach) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) i.e. couldn't do full text search so I converted back to MyISAM for now. Those MATCH queries are very slow. But that's I think a matter of a separate question.

Comment: I think it's time to upgrade! You are running a version that's at least three major versions behind current.

Answer (score 1):

This looks *wrong*:

```
    FROM  people_emails p
    JOIN  email_routing r  ON r.receiver_email_id = 3223
      AND  r.status = 2
```

`p` is not used in any `ON` clauses.  Perhaps you are missing so way to tie `p` and `r` together?  Without it, you have a "cross join".  If there are 1K rows in each, you end up with 1M rows in the join.

Also, please use `ON` for showing how tables relate; use `WHERE` for filtering (3222 & 2).